# How does @MTOM ensures file integrity when uploading/downloading file?

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, mtom

When using JAX-WS @MTOM to transfer a file, does it have a build-in file integrity check? Or you have to do it on your own after the download/upload is completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it relies on the "implicit" integrity of TCP. There isn't a layer above that within the actual protocol.